# can anyone explain me how does this function work?

Tags: c, string, function

I don't understand what this function do. Can anyone explain me in detail please?

```
char *my_getline(FILE *stream) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t pos = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getc(stream)) != EOF) {
        char *newp = realloc(line, pos + 2);
        if (newp == NULL) {
            free(line);
            return NULL;
        }
        line = newp;
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
        line[pos++] = (char)c;
    }
    if (line) {
        line[pos] = '\0';
    }
    return line;
}
```

If you can add a comment on my code, I think that will help me. I want to search a substring in a string and I found this function code.

This is the main function:

```
int main(void) {
    char *str, *sub;
    size_t len1, len2, i, count = 0;
    printf("Insert string :\n");
    str = my_getline(stdin);
    printf("insert substring :\n");
    sub = my_getline(stdin);

    if (str && sub) {
        len1 = strlen(str);
        len2 = strlen(sub);
        for (i = 0; i + len2 <= len1; i++) {
            if (!memcmp(str + i, sub, len2)) {
                count++;
                printf("Substring found at index : %d\n", i);
            }
        }
        printf("in the number of: %d\n", count);
        if (count == 0) {
            printf("Substring not found\n");
        }
    }
    free(str);
    free(sub);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand the main function but unable to understand the logic in function my_getline.

Please help me in understanding the logic. Thanks!

Comment: Can you narrow it down? Which parts of the function do you understand, which not? Please make comments `// understood` or `// ??` at each line.

Comment: It reads a whole line in the most inefficient way I could possibly imagine...

Answer (score 1):

```
char *my_getline(FILE *stream) {
    // pointer to the line to be read:
    char *line = NULL;
    // position of the next character:
    size_t pos = 0;
    // single character:
    int c;

    while ((c = getc(stream)) != EOF) { // read 1 character at a time until EOF
        // allocate a new buffer with room for the char just read + a 0 terminator
        // when `line` is NULL, this is the same as `malloc()`, otherwise it 
        // will change the size of the allocation:
        char *newp = realloc(line, pos + 2);

        // check for errors:
        if (newp == NULL) {
            free(line);
            return NULL;
        }

        // no errors, assign new buffer to `line`:
        line = newp;

        // end of line found: we're done:
        if (c == '\n')
            break;

        // otherwise add new character to the line:
        line[pos++] = (char)c;
    }

    // if there was *anything* to read, add 0 terminator (marks end of string):
    if (line) {
        line[pos] = '\0';
    }
    return line;
}
```

That's about it. Note it's horribly inefficient for two reasons: It reads only *one* character at a time and it calls `realloc()` for *each and every character*.

A better solution would use e.g. `fgets()` and increase the buffer size in reasonable chunks, for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GETLINE_CHUNK 1024

static void xrealloc(void *bufPtr, size_t size)
{
    void **buf = bufPtr;
    void *tmp = realloc(*buf, size);
    if (!tmp)
    {
        free(*buf);
        *buf = 0;
    }
    *buf = tmp;
}    

char *my_getline(FILE *stream)
{
    // allocate first chunk:
    char *buf = malloc(GETLINE_CHUNK);
    if (!buf) return 0;
    *buf = 0;
    size_t pos = 0;

    // read up to GETLINE_CHUNK bytes, until newline:
    while (fgets(buf + pos, GETLINE_CHUNK, stream))
    {
        // look for newline:
        char *nlPos = strchr(buf, '\n');
        if (nlPos)
        {
            // found, then our line is complete
            *nlPos = 0;

            // shrink buffer to needed size
            xrealloc(&buf, nlPos-buf+1);
            return buf;
        }

        // set next offset to read
        pos = strlen(buf);

        // increase buffer size to have room for a whole other GETLINE_CHUNK:
        xrealloc(&buf, pos + GETLINE_CHUNK);
        if (!buf) return 0;
    }

    // if nothing was read, free buffer and return NULL:
    if (*buf == 0)
    {
        free(buf);
        buf = 0;
    }
    return buf;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *line = my_getline(stdin);
    if (line)
    {
        puts(line);
        free(line);
    }
    else puts("no input!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @joop you're wrong, please look closely. It's just `void *` trickery.

Comment: Yes, I just saw it. I think it is overly complex. Why cast to `void*` ?

Comment: @joop using `void *` in the signature guarantees it can be called with any type of pointer. You could argue that the signature hides the fact it needs a double pointer. Unfortunately, using `void **` in the signature would require explicit casts when calling. (and I hate explicit casts of pointer types, they're often a signpost for broken code)

Comment: It will also suppress error messages and warnings. Such that it will go unnoticed when you pass it a pointer to int, or a pointer to character.

Comment: @joop you can pick one of two evils here: C allows to express "*any pointer is fine*" with `void *`, but not "*any double-pointer is fine*". (`void **` is not compatible with e.g. `char **`). If you have `void **` in the signature, it just requires the caller to write an explicit cast. The caller could still cast an `int *`, which would still go unnoticed (the explicit cast tells the compiler basically "*shut up, I know what I'm doing*")

Comment: @joop As it's impossible anyways to *ensure* a double pointer is passed, I always prefer the variant that doesn't require explicit casts. But that said, the naming of the arguments could be more clear, I'll update that.

Comment: @FelixPalmen can you add comment on my code in the same mode for the main? thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Well this function gives you line, Lets go Step by Step:

```
char *my_getline(FILE *stream) {
    char *line = NULL; //this is just pointer initialization
    size_t pos = 0; //position variable definition and init 
    int c; //a variable to store temporary character

    while ((c = getc(stream)) != EOF) //read every character till end of file  
    {
        // To dynamically allocate memory, with reference to the 
        // number of character and plus '2' is just to compensate null
        // character and the character(Since pos is 0)

        char *newp = realloc(line, pos + 2); 

        if (newp == NULL) { // this is to check whether memory was alloacted properly or not.  
            free(line); //if not free line 
            return NULL;// break the program and return NULL
        }

        line = newp;// if memory is allocated properly store allocated memory in line pointer

        if (c == '\n') //if new line is detected
            break;// break the while loop
        line[pos++] = (char)c; // store the character in dynamically allocated memory and new character in new location.
    }

    if (line) { //if line contains something then add a null character at last, to complete that string
        line[pos] = '\0';
    }

    return line; //returns the content of line.
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Well, "*can be defined as char as well*" is **wrong**. It **must** be an `int`, so it can hold any `unsigned char` value, as well as `EOF`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen as long as you are *Happy*

Comment: @VishwajeetVishu it's actually very important, using a `char` would lead to hard-to-locate bugs .. so thanks for updating the answer.

Comment: @VishwajeetVishu can you do the same thing for the main? add a comment for every line please?